# Reading a cookie, updating a new name/value to the cookie and then read the cookie again

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to read the existing Javascript cookie, add a name and value pair to that cookie. Then read the cookie again checking for whether the added name value pair is existing. if on exists i need to do the page redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how one would set a cookie and then test its value using the YUI framework.  Every framework has cookie functions which make it easier: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RahHQ/.